# How to update a column in laravel migration file which will be multiplied by 100

Tags: sql, laravel, database

in my table 'number' column, there i want to modify the column multiplied by 100. the column is decimal type.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users MODIFY number*100 Decimal(11,4) null');     
            
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

No need to modify the column. you can set an accessor in your User model.

```
public function setNumberAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['number'] = ($value * 100);
}
```